# Транспонирование строк в столбцы с группировкой

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица в postgresql, в каждой строке которой наименование товара и название магазина.
Нужно превратить название магазина в столбец и заполнить его товарами из этого магазина. Проблема в том, что названий магазинов очень много и каждый раз лопатить список для "case when Stock = " очень трудозатратно.

Сейчас:

```
#Item           #Stock
карандаш1       Венера
ручка1          Венера
маркер1         Сатурн
маркер2         Сатурн
маркер3         Сатурн
карандаш1       Сатурн
карандаш1       Плутон
карандаш2       Плутон
ручка1          Марс
ручка2          Марс
```

Нужно:

```
#Венера     #Сатурн     #Плутон     #Марс
карандаш1   маркер1     карандаш1   ручка1
ручка1      маркер2     карандаш2   ручка2
            маркер3
            карандаш1
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Вам точно не подойдут массивы в данном случае?  То есть, для ваших данных будет по строчке на магазин в формате `(магазин, массив из товаров)`.

Comment: скорее всего это нужно делать уже после селекта, не в базе данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` работает только с константным количеством
строк, так что чтобы не писав запрос вручную вывести
всё ровно в таком формате как у вас понадобится составить
запрос динамически на стороне приложения.

Есть две альтернативы. Если вы делаете запрос
для машины, и она умеет читать *SQL*-массивы,
то можете использовать `ARRAY_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT stock, ARRAY_AGG(item) FROM t_1 GROUP BY stock;
```

```
 stock  |              array_agg              
--------+-------------------------------------
 Венера | {карандаш1,ручка1}
 Плутон | {карандаш1,карандаш2}
 Сатурн | {маркер1,маркер2,маркер3,карандаш1}
 Марс   | {ручка1,ручка2}
(4 rows)
```

Если же это какой-то отчёт, который напрямую выводится
человеку, можете использовать `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT stock, STRING_AGG(item, E'\n') FROM t_1 GROUP BY stock;
```

```
 stock  | string_agg 
--------+------------
 Венера | карандаш1 +
        | ручка1
 Плутон | карандаш1 +
        | карандаш2
 Сатурн | маркер1   +
        | маркер2   +
        | маркер3   +
        | карандаш1
 Марс   | ручка1    +
        | ручка2
(4 rows)
```